# How to return nil object in non void function - swift 2.1?

Tags: core-data, swift2

Here is my code which is giving me an error

```
class Table_Users: NSManagedObject {

    class func getUserFromUserID(userID:String)->Table_Users
    {
        var user:Table_Users? = nil

        if let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
        {
            let moc = delegate.managedObjectContext


        }
        else
        {

        }
        return user
    }

}
```

It says i can't return a nil value in non-void function

what else can i return. or how should i write this function the other way ?

using

```
return user!
```

is not an option for me. because i have read that if value of object is nil, it will crash.

Comment: func getUserFromUserID(userID:String)->Table_Users?

Comment: @swiftBUTCHER : yes, thats what i needed . you could add an answer so that i can accept that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use “?” with function’s return type instead

**replace "class func getUserFromUserID(userID:String)->Table_Users" with "class func getUserFromUserID(userID:String)->Table_Users?"**

Updated Code:

```
class Table_Users: NSManagedObject {

    class func getUserFromUserID(userID:String)->Table_Users?
    {
        var user:Table_Users? = nil

        if let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
        {
            let moc = delegate.managedObjectContext


        }
        else
        {

        }
        return user
    }

}
```